# Hidden a list when user select a item in emberjs 2

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm need show a list in a route and after user selected a item show only a item for nested route. For example.

Inside
`/locals` - Show a list of locals

`locals/:id` - Here show local details and hide a local list.

How do this in EmberJS 2? Nested route don't work how I expected.

Comment: What do you mean "Nested route don't work how I expected." ? What's wrong ? Any error in the console ? Have you try to debug with the ember inspector ?

Comment: When I go to a link in next route, show the itens in previous route. There no errors in console. And yes I tried debug in inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll use an `index` route underneath the `locals` route, and show the list in the `index` route, and redirect to an individual `local` route when you select a `local`.

```
|locals
|____index
|____local
```